# JPA recursive lazy loading fails

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, recursion

I have an entity named `Menu` that has a `parent` and multiple `children` that I load using JPA. Everything works well, when the `children` is set to `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`, but if I set it to `FetchType.LAZY`, I get the error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.mydom.myapp.domain.Menu.children, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I use Hibernate 4.3.1.Final, JPA, Wildfly 10.1.0 as server, MySQL as database.

I've tried the trick with `Hibernate.initialize(menu.getChildren())` and as well calling the size()-method as in `menu.getChildren().size()`, but in both these cases I result in the same error.

I as well tried to set `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` which works, but it's pretty much like using `FetchType.Eager`, therefore not useful. Both `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` and `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` won't work.

What must I do to lazy load `menu.getChildren()`?

So, below I have the three classes that handle this matter. The method `MenuManagerController.buildNodeStructureFromMenu(TreeNode root, List<Menu> menus)` does the recursive job. This is the place where the lazy loading shall take place.

**Menu.java:**

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Menu.FIND_MENU_ROOT,
                query = "SELECT m FROM Menu m WHERE m.parent.id IS NULL")
})
public class Menu implements Serializable {
    private static final String PREFIX = "Menu.";
    public static final String FIND_MENU_ROOT = PREFIX + "findMenuRoot";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Languages languageType;
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String nameDisplay;
    private String nameAddress;
    private int position;
    @ManyToOne
    private Menu parent;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Menu> children;

    // Getters, setters, etc.
}
```

**MenuManagerController.java:**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MenuManagerController implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    private MenuService menuService;
    private Languages selectedLanguage;
    private List<Languages> languages;
    private String menuName;
    private TreeNode rootMenu;
    private TreeNode selectedMenu;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // Find root menu.
        Menu menu = menuService.findRootMenu();
        // Create root node.
        this.rootMenu = new DefaultTreeNode(menu, null);
        // Lazy load children.
        Hibernate.initialize(menu.getChildren());
        // Build Node from Menu.
        buildNodeStructureFromMenu(this.rootMenu, menu.getChildren());
    }

    private void buildNodeStructureFromMenu(TreeNode root, List<Menu> menus) {
        App.printWithTrace("Add all the " + menus.size() + " children to \"" + root.getData().toString() + "\".");

        for(Menu menu : menus) {
            App.printWithTrace("Create node for \"" + menu.getNameDisplay() + "\".");
            // Create child node of root node.
            TreeNode child = new DefaultTreeNode(menu, root);
            // Lazy load children.
            Hibernate.initialize(menu.getChildren());
            // Create all children of this menu.
            List<Menu> children = menu.getChildren();
            // Recursion.
            buildNodeStructureFromMenu(child, children);
        }
    }
}
```

**MenuService.java:**

```
@Stateless
public class MenuService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyappPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public enum Layer {
        All,
        FirstOnly
    }

    public Menu findRootMenu() {
        return this.em.createNamedQuery(Menu.FIND_MENU_ROOT, Menu.class)
                      .getSingleResult();
    }

    // More methods, etc.
}
```

Comment: You should fetch all the menu instances at once already within the `MenuService` otherwise you might lazily load relations which won't work, because you entity manager is closed after exiting `findRootMenu()`. You will either need a reference to the root in every menu so you can efficiently load all items or do a recursive query. Take a look at Blaze-Persistence for writing recursive queries: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/#recursive-ctes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says that you are trying to fetch a lazily loaded relation after your Transaction is closed.

I'd suggest you to check out my article: https://arnoldgalovics.com/lazyinitializationexception-demystified/

However, my article is written for Spring based configuration, you can easily adapt it for your case.

Answer (score 1):

you are accessing the lazy collection AFTER the associated session had been closed. 
You need to load the children with the transaction scope.
In the menu

```
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Menu findRootMenu() {
        Menu menu = this.em.createNamedQuery(Menu.FIND_MENU_ROOT, Menu.class)
                      .getSingleResult();
    //Lazy loading children with the transaction scope.
    menu.getChildren().size();
    return menu();
    }
```

2) you also use hibernate criteria query to change the fetch mode of  lazy collections to join.

```
Criteria criteria = session
                .createCriteria(Menu.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("parent.id", id))
                .setFetchMode("children", JOIN);
return this.em.createQuery(criteria)
                      .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: No effect on the initial problem. The error remains the same. Am I right assuming that the @TransactionAttribute requires the use of transactions in general? As far as I see it here, I make no use of transactions.

Comment: yes. It requires use of transactions in general.You need to define the following in your application context xml.
<tx:annotation-driven />.

Comment: The tag `<tx:annotation-driven />` is used within the Spring framework, which I am not using within the above mentioned project. Is there any way to solve the lazy loading issue with standard Hibernate / JPA?

Comment: you can also solve the same using hibernate criteria, i have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Is your 2nd example for the Hibernate Criteria a CriteriaQuery? I am having trouble trying implementing your code example. Where do you get the variable `id` from? Is that a String? As well, if I put `criteria` into `...createQuery(criteria).getSingleRes...` I get a cryptic error, preventing me from compiling.

Comment: Yes .It is criteriaQuery here where id is NULL as per your query.You need to make the criteria query using entity manger check this reference for syntax. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137875/discussion-between-socrates-and-shubham).

Answer (score -2):

I think u need to initialize children like this.

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List children = new ArrayList();